# Generate entities with Hibernate API in JAVA

Tags: java, hibernate

The idea is to have a class that, when executed, generates entities for every table in the database.
To do this, my idea was to generate entities using the Hibernate API with code.
I've been exploring a bit, and I've come up with this, where metadata is not null. However, in exporter.start(), it fails in a place where metadata is requested, and it's null there.
Currently, the class looks like this:

```
public class Hibernate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File outputPath = new File("src/main/java/com/yourcompany/invoicing/model/");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        StandardServiceRegistry registry = builder.build();
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
        Metadata metadata = sources.buildMetadata();

        System.out.println(metadata == null); // << false
        System.out.println(metadata.getDatabase().getDialect()); // << returns me mysql8 dialect

        POJOExporter exporter = new POJOExporter();
        exporter.setOutputDirectory(outputPath);
        exporter.getProperties().setProperty("jdk5", "true");
        exporter.getProperties().setProperty("ejb3", "true");

        exporter.start();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }

}
```

I have configured hibernate.cfg.xml in src/main/resources like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">r123456</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">reverse</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The hibernate.reveng.xml is also configured, although I'm not sure if it's working.

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <schema-selection match-schema="reverse" />
    <table-filter match-name=".*" package="com.yourcompany.invoicing.model" />
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

I'm using the libraries in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.buildMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.getMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.setupContext(AbstractExporter.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.POJOExporter.setupContext(POJOExporter.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:104)
    at com.yourcompany.invoicing.run.Hibernate.main(Hibernate.java:35)
```

Where

```
(AbstractExporter.java:177) is the line if(getMetadata() != null)

        if(getMetadata() != null) {
                getTemplateHelper().putInContext("md", metadata);
                getTemplateHelper().putInContext("props", getProperties());
                getTemplateHelper().putInContext("tables", metadata.collectTableMappings());
        }
```

and

```
(AbstractExporter.java:56) is the line metadata = buildMetadata();

    public Metadata getMetadata() {
        if (metadata == null) {
            metadata = buildMetadata();
        }
        return metadata;
    }
```